# Is there any decision problem not in NPH but can be reduced to a NPH problem?

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, np-hard

I just have taken an algorithm class exam and there was a T/F problem 'one can show that a problem A is in NPH by giving a polynomial reduction from A to a NPH problem B'. I know the direction of reduction is silly, but no counter examples come to mind right now...

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE.  What does NPH stand for?  What are your thoughts?  What possible examples have you thought of?  Have you tried working through a few examples where A/B are/aren't in NP?

Comment: NPH stands for NP-Hard. I don't have any possible examples but I know counter examples shouldn't be in NP otherwise counter example in NP implies P=/=NP.

Comment: Sorry, 'counter examples shouldn't be in NP' is wrong. What I mean was, as P=NP is open,  whether the counter examples exist in NP is also open.

Comment: You don't need a counter-example to show that the logic is broken.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're using many-one reductions, $\emptyset$ and $\Sigma^*$ are not **NP**-hard (exercise: prove this!), but they can be reduced to any **NP**-hard problem. Therefore, the statement, "one can show that a problem $A$ is in NPH by giving a reduction from $A$ to a NPH problem $B$" is false.

Answer (score 2):

This is the statement:

> one can show that a problem A is in NPH by giving a reduction from A to a NPH problem B

There are two cases.

1. If P = NP, then NPH contains *all* (non-trivial decision) problems. Then, the statement is silly.
2. If P ≠ NP, then any problem in P serves as a counter-example; the statement is wrong.

Hence, the statement is not something we should make; I daresay it's wrong.

---

Please check that there was no silly mistake on your or your teacher's part. The statement *is* correct if you replace NPH with NP (and use a fitting type of reduction, which is assumed).

Comment: I omitted the type of reduction by mistake. The reduction in the statement should be replaced with polynomial time reduction. Anyway, as you wrote, it is meaningless... maybe I misread NP as NPH at that time :'( ... Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I don't think there's any mistake on the teacher's part. It's a true/false question that tests whether you know the definition of **NP**-hardness and basic properties of reductions.

Answer (score 1):

Saying problem B is NP-hard means precisely that *any* problem in NP has a polynomial reduction to B.

Consequently, giving a polynomial reduction from problem A to problem B wouldn't show anything useful (assuming A is in NP) -- we already knew there was one, because we knew B was NP-hard.

So the statement is not true unless all problems in NP are NP-hard (i.e. unless P=NP).

Comment: Even if **P=NP**, $\emptyset$ and $\Sigma^*$ aren't **NP**-hard under many-one reductions.